# JSON Object restructuring advice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex, reactjs

I'm about to embark on restructuring a large quantity of JSON Object data to a different format for this class assignment i'm working on for next summer. Unfortunately, the data in its current state isn't exactly workable to my needs and I don't have a way of scraping this data in any other way. The result of scraping comes back as;

```
[
{
"classes": [
  [
    {
      "Friday": "",
      "Monday": "",
      "Tuesday": "",
      "Saturday": "",
      "Thursday": "",
      "Wednesday": ""
    },
    {
      "Friday": "",
      "Monday": "",
      "Tuesday": "",
      "Saturday": "",
      "Thursday": "",
      "Wednesday": ""
    },
    {
      "Friday": "",
      "Monday": "",
      "Tuesday": "",
      "Saturday": "",
      "Thursday": "",
      "Wednesday": "10:00 - 11:00MK4603 - LEC firstname lastname DR KBG121-12"
    }
```

The snippet above, is for the 10:00 timeslot, (27 slices representing college hours.)

Taking a look at a typical key:

```
10:00 - 11:00MK4603 - LEC firstname lastname DR KBG121-12
```

It's broken up into the following elements.

```
[10:00 - 11:00][MK4603] [-] [LEC] [firstname lastname DR] [KBG12][1-12]
Time          Module    n/a  Type  Lecturer               Room#  Weeks`
```

Time is in 24 hours, Module will exactly contain that length of char, Type is either: TUT or LEC, Lecturer is always terminated by a DR if applicable, Room is broken down to: First one-two letter's = building initials | following letter is floor with one char | following two numbers is floor number.

However sometimes (this is an edge case), the university may place two "templates" of the above in the same HTML tr box, which would result in -

10:00 - 11:00MK4603 - LEC firstname lastname DR KBG121-12 11:00 - 12:00LI4113 
   - LEC first last DR D10501-12

What would the best method of dealing with separating this sting and those alike to it into these components? I'm perfectly able to handle the development after, but I'm at a total loss on how to deal with the string as it is formatted currently. Would anyone be able to offer advice on how to go about this?

I've had some limited success with Regex as I struggle with them, however I did produce this to find the times in the string:

```
[(00-24)]*[(:)].{2}
```

Is there a more elegant or creative solution to this problem that anyone might be aware of?

Comment: Hi all just a quick note I'm aware it is currently an Array of Objects, but that will be handled later! :)

Comment: Is this format always the same? as you listed it in your template?

Comment: Yes! However one small peculiarity that I need to mention is sometimes the university provides two classes in the one HTML slot, which converts having two of these "templates" in the same key ie; 11:00:11:30 ...(the above key example)...  12:00 12:30

Comment: Please add that example too in your question.

Comment: Also, at the last string **KBG121-12** what is the rule for room number is LETTER+LETTER+LETTER+DIGIT+DIGIT ? and then it follows the weeks?

Comment: KB G 12    , so in that order: Building initials, floor, room. Initials can be one-two letters, then floor is one letter, then the following two numbers would be the room number

Comment: There is no elegant solution to badly presented data. One form of string mash (tokenisation) or another (Regex) is about your only option short of going back to the data provider and asking if there is another way to access this data.

Comment: Note also you say at the start this is JSON, and then later you speak about it being HTML. If someone is building HTML from this data you can almost guarantee there is an API somewhere which provides it in a more usable format than what you have (presumably) scraped from HTML.

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, this is originally a HTML table, however I then use a library to convert to JSON from a HTML table and store on a mysql db.  Sorry for the miscommunication. I suppose you suggest finding ways to reformat that conversion at its source?

Comment: ...and therein lies your problem. Your taking tabulated content, and trying to treat it as structured content. You  either need a better way of parsing the HTML, or as I said - go back to the source of the data. See also: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex can be found here:
https://regex101.com/r/x79lan/1/

[image]

Bellow is an explanation of all rules:

```
(
    (?P<starts_at>\d\d\:\d\d)         // the format for days, ?P<starts_at> is optional and helps giving the captured group a name. The real rule starts after this naming rule: DIGIT+DIGIT:DIGIT+DIGIT
    \s\-\s                            // space followed by dash followed by space
    (?P<ends_at>\d\d\:\d\d)           // same as starts_at group
    (?P<module_name>[^ ]*)            // capture everything until the first space
    \s\-\s                            
    (?P<module_type>[^ ]*)
    \s
    (?P<first_name>[^ ]*)
    \s
    (?P<last_name>[^ ]*)
    \s
    ([^ ]*)
    \s
    (?P<room>[A-Z]{2,3}\d\d)         // capture 2-3 letters + next two digits 
    (?P<weeks>\d-\d{1,2})            
)\s?                                 // capture everything in this BIG GROUP multiple times (this is for exception rules you added later)
```

Comment: Thank you deeply for this, I need to get to grips with Regex for the future and this will seriously help me by "showing-by-doing". I really want to thank you for taking the time for me! :) I know a better call would be to revise how I get my data, but at the moment the goal is the minimum working prototype!

Comment: @LakeSereni glad that I could help. Please ask if anything is unclear. Also try to use helper sites like regex101 as they explain in the right side everything. ;-)